# Grant Permission to Folder using PHP

Tags: php, folder-permissions

I need to grant write permission to temporary folder of all local machine (if it does not have)which access my php site. Is it possible using PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't because PHP works server-side only!
PHP is used to create HTML output and cannot access files on client-side machines.

**chmod('path/to/my/folder',777);** will only change file permissions on the server machine - never on a client!

Comment: +1, though you should format that as `chmod('path/to/my/folder', 777);`

Comment: -0 since he obviously understands the client/server side problem and is talking about localhosts which run his script, yet the command in your answer is fine.

Comment: well, i assume that he is talking about clients accessing his website because he asks for "all local machine ... which access my php site".

Comment: Thank you for caring and all of your comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the php function chmod. You want to be careful of course but you could say

```
chmod('/path/to/my/folder',777);
```

Or whatever write permissions you want.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: Well, it works, but not for the task described in this question (grant folder permissions on *client* machine).

Comment: Which means it won't work *in this context* and is a *wrong answer*.

Comment: I assumed by local machine he's talking his machine.